# Eyewriter 2.0 Compiling Errors

Tags: codeblocks, openframeworks, eye-tracking

I'm currently working on the [eyewriter 2.0](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-EyeWriter-20/), with the idea that if I can get it working, we can recommend  the DIY to our ALS patients and their families. 
However, I've been running into many complications while trying to get the software up and running.

I'm currently running Windows 8.1.

I have installed currently Code::Blocks 12.11 and OpenFrameworks v.0.7.4.

I have the openframeworks additions for Code::Blocks installed.

I have successfully run multiple example programs in openframeworks.

I have tried various combinations of C::B and OF such as the following:

```
   13.12 and v.0.8.4;
   13.12 and v.0.8.0;
   12.11 and v.0.8.0;
   12.11 and v.0.7.4;
   10.05 and v.0.6.1 FAT pre-release; 
   10.05 and v.0.6.2 FAT pre-release;
```

The most common error I have been getting is `"fatal error: gl\glew.h: no such file or directory"` for the line `#include "GL\glew.h"` in the ofConstants.h

I'm able to eliminate this error by finding the file manually and inserting the path (i.e. C:/.../.../.../glew.h). However, there are many, many, more errors similar to this which causes the manual correction to be very tedious.

I'm suspecting that the problem is due to my newb ignorance of the proper file structure. I haven't changed the structure from the zipped file which can be found on github.

Location of Workspace: `C:\openframeworks\apps\eyewriter-master\eyeWriterTracker\RemoteEyeTracker.workspace`

Location of glew.h: `C:\openframeworks\libs\openFrameworks\gl\glew.h`

Has anyone had any success building this on a windows machine? Are there any obvious mistakes that I am making? I'm fairly certain that I'm making noobish mistakes, as I'm new to frameworks and my C++ knowledge is moderately limited.

Is this perhaps easier to do in Ubuntu? I do have the possibility of using Ubuntu in Oracle VM, although not ideal as the purpose is to allow ease of communication to ALS patients and this would add another step in the process even after it's built.

I also am aware that there are already pre-compiled versions of the Eyewriter software available, but I would like to use that only as a last resort when all other resources have been exhausted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new project with projectGenerator(add neccessary addons)
2. Add files from **eyewriter** to your new project
3. That project is really old, so there will be a lot of changes, oF documentation will come in handy
4. have fun !